# Angular-cli and Ckeditor4 custom build

Tags: angular, typescript, ckeditor4.x

I'm setting my own CkEditor4 build and i need to access it from my Angular-cli application. I have no idea how to access to the ckeditor.js file which is in my Angular project.
I don't want to use the CDN.

I checked the documentation provided by CKEditor: https://ckeditor.com/docs/ckeditor4/latest/guide/dev_angular.html

I understand that i need to write somewhere those two lines somewhere in my project.

```html
<script src="my-custom-build/ckeditor.js"></script>
<script src="your-app-bundle.js"></script>
```

I have tried many solutions but none of theme work.
- put the ckeditor.js path to scripts in angular.json
- put the scripts tag in the header of index.html file

Package.Json

```
{
  "name": "web2print",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/flex-layout": "^7.0.0-beta.24",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/http": "^7.2.15",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~7.2.0",
    "angular2-image-gallery": "^7.0.0",
    "ckeditor4-angular": "^0.1.2",
    "core-js": "^2.6.8",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.17.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "ng2-ckeditor": "^1.2.2",
    "ng2-file-upload": "^1.3.0",
    "ngx-build-plus": "^7.8.3",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.2",
    "rxjs-compat": "^6.5.2",
    "screenfull": "^4.2.0",
    "tslib": "^1.9.0",
    "webpack": "^4.32.2",
    "webpack-cli": "^3.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.13.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~7.3.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.2.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.2.0",
    "@types/node": "~8.9.4",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "~3.2.2"
  }
}
```

index.html

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Web2print</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

editor.component.ts

```js
import {AfterViewChecked, Component} from '@angular/core';
import { CKEditorModule, CKEditorComponent } from 'ng2-ckeditor';



@Component( {
  selector: 'app-editor',
  templateUrl: './editor.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './editor.component.css' ]
} )
export class EditorComponent {

}
```

the error message:

```
GET http://localhost:4200/ckeditor/ckeditor.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 4):

Once you've configured your CKEditor 4 build using the [build tool](https://ckeditor.com/cke4/builder), download it, unzip it, and move it into a directory within the "assets" folder. I use a folder called "vendor":

[image: ckeditor file location]

Then set the editorUrl parameter of the ckeditor component:

```
<ckeditor [(ngModel)]="template"
  editorUrl="/assets/vendor/ckeditor/ckeditor.js"
  [config]="ckeditorConfig"
  (ready)="onEditorReady()">
</ckeditor>
```

Comment: I am getting an error "TypeError: CKEDITOR.replace is not a function"  when component is rendered. Any idea, how to resolve it?